# Is it possible to customize ADFS Sign in messages for invalid credentials

Tags: asp.net, adfs

I have a web site which do the authentication through ADFS. I have set the maximum 3 attempts as account lockout. I need to show a customize message when the user try to login after second unsuccessful attempt as "Invalid credetials.After 3rd attempt your account will be locked "

Any possible way to show this message using ADFS itself ?

Answer (score 1):

No - because the authentication attempt stays within ADFS until either successful or failed.

And the message returned is generic so as to avoid helping hackers.

From experience, what happens when the policy changes from 3 to 5? Then you would have to update your code.

Also with extranet lockout on the WAP, you can attempt infinitely but you won't get locked out because the attempt never reaches AD.